# How to get full control of MockObject's behavior?

Tags: phpunit

I need to create a PHPUnit test double that:

- uses the original implementation of some methods
- proxies some other methods to the original implementation but allows me to spy on them
- replaces yet other methods with NOP stubs with fixed return values and **doesn't** call the original implementation

**How do I?**

Between `->getMockBuilder()->getMock()`, `->createMock()`, `->createPartialMock()`, `->createTestProxy()`, and `->getMockBuilder()->enableProxyingToOriginalMethods()->setProxyTarget()` I seem to be able to  satisfy at most two of the above three requirements, but not all three.

Comment: Maybe you need to create different mocks depending on what you're testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by mock chaining:

```php
    protected function getMixedMock(
        string $className,
        array $constructorArgs,
        array $stubMethods,
        array $proxyMethods
    ) : array
    {
        $stub = $this->getMockBuilder($className)
            ->setMethods($stubMethods)
            ->getMock();

        $proxy = $this->getMockBuilder(Local::class)
            ->setConstructorArgs($constructorArgs)
            ->setMethods(array_unique(array_merge($stubMethods, $proxyMethods)))
            ->enableProxyingToOriginalMethods()
            ->setProxyTarget($stub)             // <-- CHAINING HERE
            ->getMock();

        return [$stub, $proxy];
    }

    public function test()
    {
        [$stub, $proxy] = $this->getMixedMock(
            LocalFSAdapter::class,
            ["/"],
            ['write'],
            ['has']
        );
        //methods that must be stubbed should be spied on using $stub
        //methods that must be proxied should be spied on using $proxy
        //use $proxy for testing
    }
```